# Translating 'New' arrays from VB.Net to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, arrays, new-operator

I'm trying to translate some code from VB.Net to C#, but I've run into an issue.

The Vb.Net line of code I want to translate is:

```
client.Applicants = New wcf_Integration.Applicant() {New wcf_Integration.Applicant}
```

I tried to translate it to:

```
Client.Applicants = new wcf_Integration.Applicant[1];
Client.Applicants[0] = new Applicant();
```

However, this is giving me a nasty 'Object reference is not set to an instance of an object' error.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: Hmm, the c# syntax looks ok - makes me wonder about the getter for the Applicants property.  Have you checked that?  Also, FYI, you can do it in a single line like this if you want: Client.Applicants = new [] { new wcf_Integration.Applicant() };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the array initializer syntax

```cs
// Typed implicitly (type inferred by compiler).
Clients.Applicants = new[] { new Applicant(), ... };

// Typed explicitly.
Clients.Applicants = new Applicant[] { new Applicant(), ... };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) Still get an object reference etc. error with that one.

Comment: Then Clients is null, or the property setter for Clients.Applicants does some stuff that trigger an NPE.

Comment: Thank you! I had Client = new ClientObject(); after the Clients.Applicants = new []{new Applicant()}; line when it should have been before. Silly mistake!

Answer (score 1):

May be `Client` is null. So `Client.Applicants` rises an exception. It has nothing to do with the array.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var myApplicants = new wcf_Integration.Applicant[1];
myApplicants[0] = new Applicant();
```

Comment: Or even: `Client.Applicants = new [] { new Applicant() };`